# Is it possible to define special member types of an object (like an AliasProperty) within the object literal?

Tags: powershell

It's common to create objects/pscustomobjects to store various structured data, and I personally like to add AliasProperty members to my objects for convenience/forgetfulness.

Inside an interactive shell, it's easy enough to run the `Add-Member` cmdlet to do this, but in longer code files (like my ever-growing $profile scripts), lots of successive `Add-Member` calls can start feeling pretty unclean. It's not a problem by any means, but being so imperative about it can add a lot of very explict looking lines to script files, and they all just feel unnecessarily verbose IMO**

So right now, when I define some pscustomobject in a variable using object literal syntax, it's then usually followed by a bunch of Add-Member calls to create any desired AliasProperties I might have (or other special? membertypes). For example, the following object stores 2 arrays containing the names of months in a year, and the names of days in a week:

```
$date_helpers = @{
  month_names = @('January'...)
  day_names = @('Monday'...)
}
```

Which I might then want to access via `$date_helpers.months` and `$date_helpers.days` so under the object's variable definition I would have to include 2 more lines:

```
$date_helpers | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name months -Value month_names
$date_helpers | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name days -Value day_names
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result using some syntax I'm unfamiliar with from within the variable's object literal definition? Perhaps some .net class can be prefixed as a type to the property definiton? It's also very possible that at present, there are no tricks or syntactic sugar tips for defining an object containing both properties and aliasproperty members for those properties all in one statement, but I think there should be and I'm trying to determine whether it's worth creating an issue on the [powershell github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=aliasproperty)

**might be an unpopular option. you could even argue that aliasproperties themselves are a code smell of sorts honestly. But personally, I like being quite explicit when naming things, but then I also like not having to be explicit when referencing those things later :P).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the alias properties in the same pipeline you use to create the hashtable in the first place, simply add the `-PassThru` switch parameter when calling `Add-Member`:

```
$date_helpers = @{
  month_names = @('January'...)
  day_names = @('Monday'...)
} | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name months -Value month_names -PassThru | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name days -Value day_names -PassThru
```

---

Another option is to tie the alias properties to a *type name*, rather than a specific object instance.

For that to work, we'll want to call `Update-TypeData` instead of `Add-Member`:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName EvDevsDateHelper -MemberType AliasProperty -MemberName months -Value month_names
Update-TypeData -TypeName EvDevsDateHelper -MemberType AliasProperty -MemberName days -Value day_names
```

Now that we've registered our alias properties as global type data, we just need to create an object with the target type name - to do so, create a `[pscustomobject]` instead of a hash table, at which point we can inject a type name on creation via the special `PSTypeName` key:

```
$date_helpers = [pscustomobject]@{
  month_names = @('January'...)
  day_names = @('Monday'...)
  PSTypeName = 'EvDevsDateHelper'
}
```

Since we've registered alias properties for `EvDevsDateHelper`, these aliases are now automatically available on the object, purely by virtue of the type name we injected, and `$date_helpers.days` will now yield the same value as `$date_helpers.day_names`

Comment: Oh cool that's a pretty great tip! I've made a few custom typedata additions before, but only with standard types like DateTime adding custom convert/format convenience methods, but I hadn't thought of how it could be useful for pscustomobject like you showed, thanks!